# Decompose a holomorphic function into the sum of two functions holomorphic respectively out of two campact sets

Tags: complex-analysis

I am eager to find an answer for this problem which has vexed me so much. The problem is to show that a function which is holomorphic out of two campact sets which do not intersect can be written into the sum of two functions which are holomorphic respectively out of one of the two compact sets.